# How to display 2 different classes (activities) in a fragment in ANDROID?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an already working android app, but I need to update it for better layout on tablets. I can rewrite it no-problem, but what I want to ask is;

I will have 2 fragments on screen (one for list, and one for details). When I select a customer from list, details will update itself (I have already done this without a problem). BUT, when I select an item from details fragment, it must change itself (it must be opened on details fragment, but of course it will be a different class). For example first details will be a list of details, but when I select an item from details list, it will be a different layout, maybe WebView or so..

To better represent the idea,

```
LLLLLL DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
LLLLLL DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
LLLLLL DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
LLLLLL DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
LLLLLL DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
LLLLLL DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

Where "L" is list fragment, and "D" is details fragment. But I want to show 2 (or more) different classes (activities) (Not at the same time btw) in the details fragment. How do I do that? I was searching this for 2 full days, there is nice tutorials but I couldn't find any example for this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html , Section 17 covers Fragment i hope it helps you. and one more same post Here :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a viewFlipper inside your details fragment. Of this way you can have two clases there, and navigate between then. For example:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/example_view_flipper"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/first_layout" />
  <include android:id="@+id/second"  layout="@layout/second_layout" />

</ViewFlipper>
```